# Toad for Oracle install

Tags: installation, toad

I'm beginner level oracle developer. I have SQL developer installed on my machine. And I wanted to install Toad for oracle too. But When I tried to install Toad, it gave me an error:

> No Valid Oracle Clients found. You need atleast one 64- bit client properly configured.

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: To the close voter: Come on, at your place of work, do DBAs really install Toad on the client machines???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SQL Developer ships with its own JDBC driver, which doesn't require an oracle client to connect to the Database.

If you have a compatible [Oracle Client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) sitting around, you can tell SQL Developer to piggyback on that client for connections - but THAT IS NOT required.

T.O.A.D. is a windows executable that needs an Oracle Client to connect to a database. An Instant Client is the easiest way to get going.

Comment: Also saving the cost of a licence

Comment: @ChristianPalmer true, but I was trying to keep this at the technical level

Comment: Opinion: What do you need in T.O.A.D. that SQL Developer isn't offering? Maybe we can save you a few gigabytes in software and minutes of time/config/setup.